# i am having Low image quality even after RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode to HighQuality

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, render, bitmapimage

i am having low quality image even after RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(thumbImg, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
Any idea

```
        if(File.Exists(image_file.FullName))
        {
            IPLRes.print( "Loading " + image_file.FullName);
            BitmapImage thumbImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image_file.FullName));
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(thumbImg, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
            ImageBrush imgbrush = new ImageBrush(thumbImg);
            imgbrush.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
            RenderedPages[page_numx] = imgbrush;

        }
```

.....

```
ShapRectangle thumbnail = (ShapRectangle)FindName("rect_Thumb" + thumbnail_nbr);
VISUAL thumbnailvisual = (VISUAL)FindName("rect_Thumb" + thumbnail_nbr);
thumbnail.Fill = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)RenderedPages[page_numx];
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i was able to make it work finaly by adding the RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode in the main window. thanks to stefanOlson http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Workaround-for-low-quality-bitmap-resizing-in-WPF-4.aspx

```
MainWindow()
 { 
  InitializeComponent();
  RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.Fant);
    ...........
 }
```